# GNU find "or" function is not working with -print0 | xargs -0 tar

Tags: shell, unix, gnu-findutils

I'm using this command to find specific files (2 files) which works as it should be on it's own;

```
find . -iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.pdf'
```

and returns the correct files;

```
./.folder1/file1.txt
./.folder1/file1.pdf
./.folder2/file2.txt
./.folder2/file2.pdf
```

However, if I try to make these founded files into a tarball, it only includes the first `-iname` part from the find command, like this;

```
find . -iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 tar -czvf files.tar.gz
```

so it doesn't include the `*.pdf`s in this example and only includes `*.txt`s in the tarball:

```
./.folder1/file1.txt
./.folder2/file2.txt
```

how can I fix this so it makes both `*.txt`s and `*.pdf`s into a tarball?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, using `find ... | xargs tar -c` is not well-advised: When `find` generates a list of files so long that `xargs` splits into multiple `tar` invocations, all but the last invocation will be overwritten.

Much safer to run just one copy of `tar`, and configure *that* to read from stdin:

```
find . '(' -iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.pdf' ')' -print0 |
  tar -c --null -T - -zf backups.tar.gz
```

---

Writing a shell equivalent to your `find` logic, the original/buggy version might look like this:

```
for f in *; do
  { [[ $f = *.txt ]]; } || \
  { [[ $f = *.pdf ]] && printf '%s\0' "$f"; }
done
```

There's nothing actually *done* if the `*.txt` branch is true, because the `printf` is only conditional on the `*.pdf` case.

---

Either use parens to group your branches:

```
find . '(' -iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.pdf' ')' -print0
```

...which makes the logic look like:

```
for f in *; do
  { [[ $f = *.txt ]] || [[ $f = *.pdf ]]; } && printf '%s\0' "$f";
done
```

---

Or put a separate copy of the action on each side:

```
find . -iname '*.txt' -print0 -o -iname '*.pdf' -print0
```

...which acts like:

```
for f in *; do
  { [[ $f = *.txt ]] && printf '%s\0' "$f"; } || \
  { [[ $f = *.pdf ]] && printf '%s\0' "$f"; }
done
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to reply, this one worked like a charm! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

`-o` has lower precedence than the implicit `-a` that joins `-iname '*.pdf'` and `-print0`. You need to parenthesize the arguments to `-o`:

```
find . \( -iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.pdf' \) -print0
```

`find` only adds an implicit `-print` if there are *no* actions specified at all. Without the parentheses, you have an explicit `-print0`, which prevents an implicit `-print` being applied to the result of the first `-iname` primary.